# Draw Base64 png data with phaser.js

Tags: javascript, base64, phaser-framework

I'm making a game with Phaser and I want to take a screenshot from one scene and draw it to another by using `game.canvas.toDataURL();`.

So far, in the first scene I've tried:

```
GAME.cc = game.canvas.toDataURL();
```

and then in the second one:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var base = new PIXI.BaseTexture(this),
                texture = new PIXI.Texture(base);

    var sp = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
    sp.setTexture(texture);
};

img.src = GAME.cc;
```

There's no error in the console, but the sprite is completely black. So ... what's the problem?

[image: demo]

Comment: Have you tried importing the data with `this.game.cache.addImage('key',null,imageData);`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

The first is to force the Canvas renderer when you create your game. For example:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '', {
    preload: preload, create: create, update: update
});
```

As evident in your screenshot, you're currently using either `Phaser.AUTO` or `Phaser.WEBGL`, which is allowing the WebGL renderer.

The second option is to set [`preserveDrawingBuffer`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Game.html#preserveDrawingBuffer) when you create your game.

Supposedly this will work:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game({
    width:800, height:600, renderType:Phaser.AUTO, parent:'', preserveDrawingBuffer:true
});
```

But in TypeScript (and probably vanilla JavaScript based upon what TS spits out) so should this:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
    preload: preload, create: create, update: update
});
game.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
```

Comment: "Supposedly this will work" part didn't work for me, and after looking at the Phaser.Game code, I don't understand why should it. But the last code snippet worked like a charm, thank you. Would you consider removing the dubious suggestion in favor of the working one?

Comment: The docs suggest it can be passed, https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/PIXI.WebGLRenderer.html#preserveDrawingBuffer, for the same reason it can be set later. The renderer may have something to do with why it doesn't work with the first block, if I remember correctly.